# Can't get the expected result of my program in C++ with assembly insertion

Tags: c++, assembly, x86

I learn Assembly and I need to write a program that should output "yes" or "no" depending on whether the number included in the interval. But 0 is always displayed. How do I need to change the program code to get the correct result?

I've tried to add new label for numbers that are included in the interval, but I got a similar result.

```
short a = 5, b = 10;
short n;
cout << "Enter number:";
cin >> n;
short yes = 1;
__asm
{
    mov ax, a
    mov bx, b
    mov cx, n
    cmp ax, bx
    ja no
    cmp bx, cx
    ja no
    jmp exit
    no:
        mov yes, 0
    exit:
}
if (yes == 0) cout << "no";
else cout << "yes";
```

I expect to get "yes" if the input number is greater than 4 or less than 11, but the actual output is always "no".

Comment: You are comparing `cmp ax, bx` which are the two ends of the interval not your input number. You probably wanted `cmp ax, cx` and you also got the other test reversed. Furthermore `short` is signed but `ja` is unsigned. You probably want `jg`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I fixed `cmp ax, bx` to `cmp ax, cx` and `ja` to `jg`, but the program is still working incorrectly.

Comment: Should probably be `cmp ax, cx`, `jg no`, `cmp bx, cx`, `jl no`

Comment: I fixed it too, and now I have this: "Process finished with exit code 2130567168"